# Is there a way to tweak Excel 2007, with an add-in perhaps, to enable it to save spreadsheets in the dbase IV file format?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I know one can open dBase IV files with Excel 2007, but, unfortunately, you cannot save files to that format. It is only possible in Excel 2003.

Is there an add-in one can use in Excel 2007?

Comment: I have found an add-in that can do the conversion: http://thexlwiz.blogspot.com/2009/09/update-save-dbf-in-excel-2007.html. I will try it on Monday on my work computer which has Excel 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an add-in for Excel 2007 that does the job, on this [blog](http://thexlwiz.blogspot.com). The add-in is called SaveDBF.

Comment: Nice find!

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be various converters to/from dBase here: 
[dbfView](http://www.dbfview.com/csv-dbf.html)

I see options for [Excel 2003](http://www.dbfview.com/convert-xls-to-dbf.html), [2007](http://www.dbfview.com/import-xlsx-files-to-dbf.html), and [CSV](http://www.dbfview.com/csv-dbf.html) there.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this. But you can export to, let's say, csv file, and then use converter to get your dBase file. I believe getting CSV (or other open format) to dBase converter is much easier than trying to convert directly to dBase from Excel.

Comment: @Andrejs, Thanks alot. Could you perhaps recommend such a converter?

Comment: Try the one mentioned by Sanjay Sheth.