# Is Workbook.FileFormat available to the Excel UI (specifically when the file type can't be saved)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, file-format

As a programmer I eventually located the file type of a `.d` extension file loaded successfully by Excel 2007 by interrogating `Workbook.FileFormat` via VBA, but can a normal user determine it is a DBF4 file when it is [not saveable](https://superuser.com/questions/35034/is-there-a-way-to-tweak-excel-2007-with-an-add-in-perhaps-to-enable-it-to-save) (without addins)?

(Specifically when you choose Save As, normally the existing file format is selected.)

FYI I've already checked Prepare > Document Properties, but I see nothing there. IIRC previous versions of Excel (or I might be thinking of Word) had the option to always display the file conversion dialogue box when opening a file, but I can't see a way to do so with Excel 2007 (and, in any case, the file *isn't* being converted -- it is being opened as a DBF4 file format).

Comment: Have you seen [this workaround](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/34102)? It's not .fileformat so it's not an "answer"

Comment: @Raystafarian: Your comment above may be worthwhile as an answer to the [linked](http://superuser.com/questions/35034/is-there-a-way-to-tweak-excel-2007-with-an-add-in-perhaps-to-enable-it-to-save) question.

Comment: The Excel 2007-2010 32-bit add-in called SaveDBF might be of help. You can try out the demo at thexlwiz.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

Per this [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-HP010014103.aspx#BMexcelformats)

> dBase III and IV. You can open these files formats in Excel, but you
>   cannot save an Excel file to dBase format.

Unfortunately, there is not a `.fileformat` for `.dbf`

Comment: As the question implies, I now know Excel 2007 is able to open these files, but I cannot determine a way for a normal user to determine what has happened.