# How can I save my excel spreadsheet in DBF format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, export, dbf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Workbook.FileFormat available to the Excel UI (specifically when the file type can't be saved)](https://superuser.com/questions/291903/is-workbook-fileformat-available-to-the-excel-ui-specifically-when-the-file-typ)

How can I save my excel spreadsheet in DBF format? I used to be able to do this directly from excel, but they seem to have disabled this in the 2010 version.

I'd rather not install a whole new office suite to do this (e.g. open office, not withstanding its awesomeness) but would be happy to use a free, small utility or excel add-on if it is available.

Comment: You can copy/paste the data into Access... which does save dbf.  If you have ArcGIS software from ESRI, you can use ArcCatalog to export xls to dbf.

Answer (score 0):

[XLS Converter](http://www.xls-converter.com/) is a tool that can do this for you. There is a trial version that is free.

**Note:** It can also do xlsx files, despite the name.